# drawing canvas FC

Tags: android, eclipse, drawing, android-canvas

I have a drawing canvas with no errors but keeps force closing. I am not sure why it is force closing. I know nothing about canvases if some one could hep me that would be great.

**Log cat errors**

```
05-03 10:07:12.803: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14042): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-9

05-03 10:07:12.803: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14042): java.lang.NullPointerException

05-03 10:07:12.803: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14042):     at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfRecycled(Canvas.java:954)

05-03 10:07:12.803: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14042):     at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:980)

05-03 10:07:12.803: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14042):     at com.the.line.Panel.onDraw(Panel.java:59)
```

**This is from line 59 of my Panel class**

```
canvas.drawBitmap(kangoo, 10, 10, null);

05-03 10:07:12.803: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14042):     at com.the.line.CanvasThread.run(CanvasThread.java:28)
```

**This is from line 28 of my CanvasThread class**

```
_panel.onDraw(c);
```

I found this code from a tutorial [here](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-use-canvas-your-android-apps-part-1) if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out the problem was in my `setContentView` it was set to 'setContentView(R.layout.main)' witch I am not using any xml file in this so when I changed the `SetContentView` to `setContentView(new Panel(this,null));` it worked fine.

Comment: Me too. I was getting kinda frustrated with it.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at Canvas.java

```
private static void throwIfRecycled(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (bitmap.isRecycled()) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap " + bitmap);
    }
}
```

The only way this would throw a NPE is if bitmap was null.

Can you check to make sure kangoo is not null?

Comment: kangoo is set to null. I changed it to paint but it still force closes

Comment: if kangoo == null you will get the exception that you posted.  When it is not null are you saying you get the same exception?  Or is it at a different location?

Comment: When I took away the null I did get the same exception.

Comment: The only way that line in Canvas.java throws the exception you posted is if the bitmap passed in is NULL. How did you "take away the null"?

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't make sense to me.  How can you replace a Bitmap in the call canvas.drawBitmap(kangoo, 10, 10, null); with paint?  The problem is kangoo == null.  The null for the paint is just fine.  However you are trying to initialize kangoo is resulting in it being null.

Comment: No. kangoo needs to be a valid Bitmap.

Comment: Okay, I am sorry for the dumb questions. I haven't ever worked with canvas and and that stuff much. I have another dumb question though, my kangoo is in PNG form should it be some other format?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing more of the code would help, but based off of the tutorial you linked to, it looks like your image resource is not available.  Did you use the `R.drawable.kangoo` code or did you do something else?

```
Bitmap kangoo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                            R.drawable.kangoo);
```

Comment: I did use the kangoo drawable and that all the code that have is from the tutorial.